# Cant get flow working with atom

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, flowtype, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app and wanted to install flow and have linter-flow package in atom running. I followed the install instructions on the flow website, installed the atom package but atom complains that it can't find flow and if I try and run "npm run flow" I see the following in my terminal:
"Attempting to kill server for ... Unable to figure out pids of running Flow server. Try manually killing i..."

Any one know what may be wrong? Do I need to install globally first

Comment: What is the `flow` script you've added in `package.json`?

Comment: Here is my package.json: https://pastebin.com/i9YZAdK8

Myabe I need to specify the full path to flow?

Comment: Pls. also tell us the Flow version. For example, WebStorm has no problems with Flow up to 0.59 but cannot start the very latest 0.60 version server because something changed in how the IDE should run or communicate with the Flow server. -- *EDIT:* I see you have 0.60. Given my WebStorm experience, how about 0.59, could you try that previous version? I don't know how it is used by Atom though.

Comment: Fixed... using version 0.59.0 did it. Must be something wrong with 0.60.0 like you say. Thanks ofr the help

Comment: Flow issue created (Github): https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5444 -- Show your support by upvoting... :-)